# Spring Boot + JdbcTemplate has unexplained query slowness?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, connection-pooling

I'm using Spring Boot with JdbcTemplate and the default Tomcat connection pool.

When I hit a route in my MVC application, it runs a query using JdbcTemplate. Here are the logs:

```
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.441 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.443 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE tokens SET last_accessed = NOW() where token = ?]
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.444 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.451 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.452 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.457  INFO 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] e.u.d.d.w.e.u.d.d.w.c.CensusController   : Before census query:Fri Sep 16 16:04:34 PDT 2016
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.458 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.459 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT o.acad_term_code, o.crse_num, o.acad_subject_code, sum(s.current_enrol_cnt) as current_enrol_cnt, sum(o.max_enrol_cnt) as max_enrol_cnt, s.snapshot_code, sum(s.wait_cnt) as wait_cnt FROM course_sect_snapshot s INNER JOIN course_sect_offering o ON s.crn_num = o.crn_num AND s.acad_term_code = o.acad_term_code AND s.vers = o.vers WHERE s.vers = (SELECT max(vers) FROM cdw_vers WHERE import_finished IS NOT NULL) AND o.acad_subject_code = ? AND o.crse_num = ? AND s.snapshot_code IN ('INSTR_BEG', 'CURRENT', 'DAY5', 'DAY10', 'DAY15') GROUP BY o.acad_term_code, o.acad_subject_code, o.crse_num, s.snapshot_code ORDER BY o.acad_term_code, o.crse_num]
Sep 16 16:04:34 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:34.460 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
Sep 16 16:04:42 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:42.243 DEBUG 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
Sep 16 16:04:42 beta.dw java[24249]: 2016-09-16 16:04:42.244  INFO 24249 --- [io-8080-exec-10] e.u.d.d.w.e.u.d.d.w.c.CensusController   : After census query:Fri Sep 16 16:04:42 PDT 2016
```

As you can see, it takes about 8 seconds between "Fetching JDBC Connection" and "Returning JDBC Connection."

However, the query doesn't take 8 seconds. Running the same query on the same server via the 'mysql' command shows the exact query (with the same parameters filled in) takes about 1.8s.

Where are the missing 6.2s coming from? I suspect the Tomcat connection pool - for example, when I perform my first query after starting up Spring Boot, only then -- not on launch but on page load -- does the Tomcat connection pool bother to gather connections.

Any ideas how to go about debugging this?

Comment: By the looks of it, it seems that you have a connection leak. Your application code may not be releasing connections correctly. It is impossible to say where the problem is without seeing your entire code where you obtain a connection, use it and release it. Also note that some connection pools (Tomcat included) are poor at reclaiming connections. Using a more recent pool like HikariCP or BoneCP could give you better results.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a performance issue related to MySQL running in a VM.